# Pushing items to an array in typescript with key value

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I would like to push an array to another array but the result generates an incorrect result

```
let pusheditems:any[]  = [];
pusheditems.push(this.yesvalue);
pusheditems.push(this.selectedtruck);
```

Later when i `console.log(pusheditems)`

Am getting an array of type

```
array(0->yes array, 1->select truck array)
```

What am looking for is to change the index values of 0,1 to strings like yes, truck

So i would expect to get

```
array(yes->yes array, truck->select truck array)
```

I have also tried

```
pusheditems.push({yes:this.yesvalue});  //adding yes
pusheditems.push({truck:this.selectedtruck}); //adding truck
```

But this doesnt work

The values of

```
this.yesvalues and this.selectedtruck are also arrays
```

What do i need to add further

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thing you are trying to achieve is to create object, not an array.

You can do it:

```
let pusheditems = {};
pusheditems[this.yesvalue] = this.selectedtruck;
```

Answer (score 13):

In Typescript, arrays can have keys only of type number. You need to use `Dictionary` object, like:

```
    let pusheditems: { [id: string]: any; } = {};    // dictionary with key of string, and values of type any
    pusheditems[this.yesvalue] = this.selectedtruck; // add item to dictionary
```